# CSV, PDF, Excel files being downloaded as blob in export extension of dataTables

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, datatables

I wrote a demo for exporting the data in various formats:
**HTML code:**

```
<div class="container" style="position: relative;top:60px;">
        <div class="row">
            <table id="empTable" class="display table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Designation</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Extension</th>
                        <th>Joining Date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Designation</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Extension</th>
                        <th>Joining Date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
var editor;
    $('#empTable').dataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        "ajax": "empdata.json",
        "columns": [{
            "data": "name"
        }, {
            "data": "designation"
        }, {
            "data": "office"
        }, {
            "data": "extension"
        }, {
            "data": "joining_date"
        }, {
            "data": "salary"
        }],
        select: true,
        buttons: [
            {
            extend: 'collection',
            text: 'Export',
            buttons: [
                'copy',
                'excel',
                'csv',
                'pdf',
                'print'
            ],  
        }]
        /*buttons: [{
            extend: 'create',
            editor: 'myEditor',
            formButtons: [{
                label: 'cancel',
                fn: function() {
                    this.close();
                }
            }]
        }]*/
    });
```

And here is jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/3x0pa64o/
When I download table data in various formats, it downloads as `blob`, but not as `csv`, `pdf`, `excel`... What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with "it downloads as blob, but not as csv, pdf, excel". It simply lacks the file name in your example.

As stated in https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/filename.html and https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/flash/filename.html

By default the name of the file created by the ... button types will automatically be taken from the document's title element.

So you set the file name in `title` element:

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/qLqugynb/

Comment: Thanks, buddy... fixed it